# How to compile the currently installed kernel from the Ubuntu source

Tags: kernel, 21.04

I would like to recompile my current kernel from source with debug flags. (ubuntu 21.04)

Specifically I'd like all the Ubuntu defaults and modules installed. In particular I'd like to have the zfs module be installed as it is in ubuntu.

I found this reference https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile It looks old. Is there a newer version.

Also is there any guide on how to pick the different debug flags. I am interested in debugging the VT switch specifically when using gnome/gdm. I have a situation where it gets stack in WAITACTIVE mode and blank screen. I'd like to understand the switch and modify my setup accordingly.

If there is a simpler way of understanding/debugging the VT switch I'll appreciate.